# PowerShell: Unrecognized escape sequence

Tags: powershell

I have the following code:

```
$BuildDetails = Get-Content "d:\BuildDetails.txt"

[regex]$BuildDetailsRY = '\bRY:\s+\K\S+'
[regex]$BuildDetailsRoY = '\bRoY:\s+\K\S+'
[regex]$BuildDetailsSP = '\bSP:\s+\K\S+'
[regex]$BuildDetailsRC = '\bRC:\s+\K\S+'
[regex]$BuildDetailsBranch = '\bBranch:\s+\K\S+'

$ReleaseYear = $BuildDetails | Select-String $BuildDetailsRY -AllMatches | Foreach-Object {$_.Matches} | 
       Foreach-Object {$_.Groups[2].Value}

Write-Host Release Year = $ReleaseYear
```

When I run it i get the following error:
Cannot convert value "\bSP:\s+\K\S+" to type "System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex". Error: "parsing "\bSP:\s+\K\S+" -
Unrecognized escape sequence \K."

This is the text file it is looking in.

```
RY: 17
RoY: 2
SP: 0
RC: 1
Branch: $/Release/17.2.x
```

What I want the REGEX to do is find the data after the title e.g. 17

Comment: Yes, your regex is invalid and the error message reflects that. `\k` needs angle brackets and a name, and a previous capture group with that name, it's [a named backreference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) or maybe nothing in capitals. What are you asking? What is your `\K` intended to match? Do you mean `\\K` for a literal backslash-k ?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I have added more details around what it is searching for within the text file. I have tested the regex on [link](https://regex101.com/) with my text file and it works fine.

Comment: Regex101.com is useful, but it only handles four regex engines (PCRE - Perl Compatible Regex Engine, GoLang, Python and JavaScript). .Net is different again, its own regex engine. Great for the basics, but \k is different in PCRE and .Net. something like http://regexhero.net/tester/ or http://regexstorm.net/tester can do .Net regexes online - but then, PowerShell does .Net regex, so they only tell you the same thing it tells you.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a better way in the end:

```
$BuildDetails = Get-Content "D:\BuildDetails.txt"

[regex]$BuildDetailsRY = '(?<=RY: ).*?(?=\s)'
[regex]$BuildDetailsRoY = '(?<=RoY: ).*?(?=\s)'
[regex]$BuildDetailsSP = '(?<=SP: ).*?(?=\s)'
[regex]$BuildDetailsRC = '(?<=RC: ).*?(?=\s)'
[regex]$BuildDetailsBranch = '(?<=Branch: ).*'

$ReleaseYear = [regex]::matches($BuildDetails, $BuildDetailsRY)
$ReleaseofYear = [regex]::matches($BuildDetails, $BuildDetailsRoY)
$SP = [regex]::matches($BuildDetails, $BuildDetailsSP)
$RC = [regex]::matches($BuildDetails, $BuildDetailsRC)
$Branch = [regex]::matches($BuildDetails, $BuildDetailsBranch)
```